# Multiple Lingual support for html form

Tags: php, html

I have a requirement where the application needs to let user type in different languages. Like, I have a html textarea where user can type his comments. He can choose to type in English/Kannada/Chinese/Japanese etc. More like how gmail allows user to choose the language he wishes to type. So if user chooses to type in Hindi, what ever he types in English is actually converted to Hindi. Is there a way to achieve this.

As of now I am able to define the Database column as "CHARACTER SET utf8" and display the comments in the appropriate language. However, user needs to copy and paste the content from a different source to the text area(E.g user types in this comment in gmail in Hindi and copy and paste the content into the text-area and submits.).

Comment: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:language

Comment: Do you want the input to be automatically translated to another language?

Comment: Yes. I want the the input to be automatically translated as i type in. Say my base language is English and choose to type something in Japanese/Chineese. As i type something in English, it should be translated to Japanese automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for IME like that is used in Wikipedia? Please try jQuery IME. 
https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.ime

Examples
http://thottingal.in/projects/js/jquery.ime/examples/

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes. Exactly. I want a IME, that changes the text entered in English to the a selected language automatically and dynamically. I tried the link provided by you. I could not understand how to use it. If you can brief me about how to use it, it would be great

Comment: If my answer is correct, please mark this answer as correct by clicking the green checkmark. Usage is not too complicated. #1. Include required CSS and JS files(jQuery, IME files). #2. Attach IME support in your input box or text area by using the line $( 'textarea' ).ime(); or $( '#inputbox_id' ).ime(); . You can check the source code in http://thottingal.in/projects/js/jquery.ime/examples/

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

There is the popular [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3alanguage) which I have used:

There is also a html5 wysiwyg editor Aloha which I know of, but have not used.

[Language files](http://www.aloha-editor.org/guides/translations.html) for Aloha

There are others beside which you can search for, you may find one that supports all the languages you seek.